# Deployment of Java8u77 removes static installation of Java6u45

Tags: java, installation, deployment

I'm using the free version of PDQ Deploy to deploy Java updates on client computers in a domain, using the executable installers, NOT the extracted MSI.

According to [the Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/config.html#table_config_file_options), there is no need to create a config file. Command line switches are possible with the same values.

Some of our clients require Java 6 to remain installed. That's why I perform a [static installation](http://If%20you%20perform%20a%20static%20installation%20of%20the%20JRE%20(by%20specifying%20the%20command-line%20or%20configuration%20file%20option%20STATIC=1),%20then%20the%20Java%20Auto%20Update%20feature%20will%20leave%20that%20JRE%20installed%20during%20a%20Java%20update.%20A%20later%20version%20of%20the%20same%20JRE%20family%20will%20be%20installed%20in%20a%20separate%20directory.%20This%20mode%20ensures%20that%20vendors,%20who%20require%20a%20specific%20version%20of%20the%20JRE%20for%20their%20product,%20can%20be%20certain%20that%20the%20JRE%20will%20not%20be%20overwritten%20by%20a%20newer%20version.%20%20The%20default%20installation%20directory%20of%20a%20static%20JRE%20is%20C:%5CProgram%20Files%20(x86)%5CJava%5Cjren%20(for%2032-bit%20versions)%20or%20C:%5CProgram%20Files%5CJava%5Cjren%20(for%2064-bit%20versions),%20where%20n%20is%20the%20full%20Java%20SE%20release%20and%20update%20number%20(for%20example,%20n%20=%201.8.0_20%20for%20release%208%20update%2020).) on those clients.

Now here is my challenge: When I deploy the latest version (Java 8u91) on those clients, Java 6 gets removed.

Those are the commands i'm using:

```
jre-6u45-windows-i586.exe /s STATIC=**1** SPONSORS=**0**
jre-8u91-windows-i586.exe INSTALL_SILENT=1 AUTO_UPDATE=0 REBOOT=0 SPONSORS=0 REMOVEOUTOFDATEJRES=1
```

or

```
jre-6u45-windows-i586.exe /s STATIC=**Enable** SPONSORS=**Disable**
jre-8u91-windows-i586.exe INSTALL_SILENT=1 AUTO_UPDATE=0 REBOOT=0 SPONSORS=0 REMOVEOUTOFDATEJRES=1
```

I've tested both options "Enable" or "1" / "Disable" or "0"

It's not really an option to use "REMOVEOUTOFDATEJRES=0" because I don't want those clients having Java6u45 and Java8u71 and Java8u73 and Java8u77 and Java8u91 installed at the same time...

So here is my question: does a "static installation" normally get removed if I use "REMOVEOUTOFDATEJRES=1" or am I doing it wrong?

They don't really mention it on the documentation, instead they talk about Java Auto Update:

> If you perform a static installation of the JRE (by specifying the command-line or configuration file option STATIC=1), then the Java Auto Update feature will leave that JRE installed during a Java update. A later version of the same JRE family will be installed in a separate directory. This mode ensures that vendors, who require a specific version of the JRE for their product, can be certain that the JRE will not be overwritten by a newer version.

On [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/patch-in-place-and-static-jre-installation.html) about Java 7 they say:

> When a JRE is installed in static mode, it will not be updated in place by later versions. A later version from the same JRE family will be installed in a separate directory. This mode ensures that vendors, who require a specific version of the JRE for their product, can be certain that the JRE will not be overwritten by a later version.
>
> Some of the characteristics of a static JRE installation are as follows:
>
> A static JRE installation (for example, 7 Update 15) will ignore a previous patch-in-place installation of another JRE (for example, 7 Update 10)
>
> A static JRE installation is **never overwritten** by another JRE version
>
> When a newer JRE version is present (for example, 7 Update 15), older JRE versions (for example, 7 Update 12) are **installed in static mode only**
>
> A patch-in-place JRE can be overwritten by a static JRE installation of the same version. The user will be left with one static JRE installation.

The only thing to get it right is to install Java 8 first, and then Java 6. But this doen't make it easy for deployment when I have to update all clients to the latest version...

Does anyone have a better solutions for this?

Thanks a lot!